# get the list of years onwards base from the given start year

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the list of years onwards base from the given start year?

I tried

```
var start_year = "2011",d = new Date( "01 " + start_year),first = d.getFullYear();
console.log(first);
```

the expected output should be,

> 2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016

where 2016 is the latest date.

but seems not working at all, any ideas, help please?

Comment: why not make a loop and increment until you reach the current/latest year?

Comment: `var start_year = 2011,
  curr_year = new Date().getFullYear(),
  arr = [start_year];
while (start_year !== curr_year) {
  ++start_year;
  arr.push(start_year);
}
console.log(arr);`

Comment: `for (let startYear = 2011, i = startYear, currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(); i <= currentYear; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var start_year = 2011;//If you receive as a string , let it be a string
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
for (var i = start_year; i <= current_year; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

In your code, `d = new Date( "01 " + start_year)` it will say `Invalid Date`

For Better answers, check comment from Rayon and Idea from dandavis.

Comment: `"2011"` => `2011`

Comment: @Tushar It converts(casts) successfully. I tried it in the console

Comment: the number can be given as a string, that's perfectly valid. don't use `parseInt()`... if you must, just hard-code `2011` instead of `"2011"`... if you used a number, you don't need the `i` variable, you can just increment and collect `start_year`...

Comment: @GopsAB, Now it is looking so _UGLY_ Dandavis is talking about `var start_year = 2011;
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
for (; start_year <= current_year; start_year++) {
  console.log(start_year);
}`